# How to import Eclipse warnings?

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-warnings

In Netbeans, when I call an overridable method from a constructor, it clearly displays a warning.

In Eclipse however, I do not get such a warning message for this specific use case. I would like to have Eclipse generate a warning here, to detect as much potential code flaws as possible.

1. Are there any "warning packs" available for Eclipse?
2. Should I install a plugin?

Comment: If I wanted to get downvoted, I'd post "don't use the Greek tragedy that is Eclipse; instead use a better IDE such as IntelliJ or Netbeans"

Comment: @BrianRoach Sometimes you can't choose which one you use. I prefer Netbeans, though.

Answer (score 0):

There are plugins for PMD, Findbugs and Checkstyle for that job. In that case i'd go with Findbugs. You can easily install it via marketplace.